# JAX-RS query with multiple parameters of the same name

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I want to make a web-service where you can query for generic data. So, my URL would be something like this:

.../field_name/Country/field_value/US/field_name/City/field_value/Boston

what would be the way to read it with Jersey - I want to get an array of field names and a corresponding array of field values.

Comment: Why not just US/Boston? Why do you need `field_name/Country/field_value`?

Comment: the names are dynamic, I don't know the order, I want client to tell me what they want to filter on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would seem to be better suited for query parameters and not url parameters as you have above.

Your url would then look something like:

```
/query?Country=US&City=Boston&City=Chicago
```

JAX-RS supports multiple query parameters of the same name by mapping them to a Collection in your endpoint as follows:

```
@GET
@Path("/query")
public String queryValues(@QueryParam("Country") List<String> countries,
                          @QueryParam("City") List<String> cities) {
   // Do work here
}
```

If the query parameters are completely dynamic and you don't know what they are until runtime then you can inject the `UriInfo` object and interrogate the query string yourself.

```
@GET
@Path("/query")
public String queryValues(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
   // Do work here
}
```

Comment: I get the parameters from a file that I parse, so they are available at runtime but not at compilation time. I guess I would need the second approach and parse the uriInfo

Comment: Does it also works in `@POST` queries with `@FormParam`s?

Answer (score 1):

**Adding an observation**: For Jersey 2.35 *FormParam*, it needs to be City=Boston&City=Chicago style, which then can become elements of a list or set.

The comma separated parameter values (e.g City=Boston,Chicago) doesn't seem to work. It takes it as a single value (Tested with Postman)

Answer (score 0):

About your query,you can use below comma separated format as well:

```
/query?Country=US&City=Boston,Chicago
```